# Meteor minSdkVersion not read by the Google Play Console

Tags: cordova, meteor, google-play-console

When adding the apk file to the google play console, the minimum API level information is not read.
In the mobile-config.js file I set the following parameters:

```
App.setPreference('android-targetSdkVersion', '28');
App.setPreference('android-minSdkVersion', '24');
```

target sdk works but google play console sets min sdk to API Level 19+. Is there a way to set this correctly? I would like to support applications with android 7.0+

Comment: If you still don't get any answers, you may try the [Meteor forums](https://forums.meteor.com/) and link to this question here, too.

Answer (score 1):

> target sdk works

No, this doesn't work. Target SDK version is set to the same value in [Cordova's  build.gradle file](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/rel/8.1.0/bin/templates/project/build.gradle).

`Meteor` depends on `Cordova` to build your application and Cordova only allows for 
configuring values that are not explicitly set in its own `build.gradle` configuration.

This following code chunk effects this restriction:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/rel/8.1.0/bin/templates/cordova/lib/config/GradlePropertiesParser.js#L82

```
    _configureProperties (properties) {
        // Iterate though the properties and set only if missing.
        Object.keys(properties).forEach(key => {
            let value = this.gradleFile.get(key);

            if (!value) {
          //....
        });
    }
```

You can rely on information provided in this table about what android SDK versions are supported.
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#requirements-and-support.

Cordova version `8.x.x` covers API levels 19-28 and equivalent Android versions are `4.4` - `9.0.0`

You shouldn't be configuring this value given that the Android version you are looking to support is already blanketed in the Android versions covered by Cordova version `8.x.x`